How to read a local file from a Yew component
I have a Yew component whose html output is completely defined by the data contained in a local file on the server disk.
I can't read this local file (is the server sandboxed?)
Is there a way to read a file from a Yew component?
struct MyComponent {
    config: Option<String>,
}

enum Msg {
    LoadConfig,
    ConfigLoaded(String),
}

impl Component for MyComponent {
    type Message = Msg;
    type Properties = ();

    fn create(ctx: &Context<Self>) -> Self {
        let config = None;

        ctx.link().send_message(Msg::LoadConfig);

        Self { config }
    }

    fn update(&mut self, ctx: &Context<Self>, msg: Self::Message) -> bool {
        match msg {
            Msg::LoadConfig => {
                let link = ctx.link().clone();
                spawn_local(async move {
                    let response = Request::get("/static/config.json")
                        .send()
                        .await
                        .unwrap()
                        .text()
                        .await
                        .unwrap();
                    link.send_message(Msg::ConfigLoaded(response));
                });
                false
            }
            Msg::ConfigLoaded(config) => {
                self.config = Some(config);
                true 
            }
        }
    }

    fn view(&self, _: &Context<Self>) -> Html {
        match &self.config {
            Some(config) => html! { <div>{ config }</div> },
            None => html! { <div>{ "Loading..." }</div> },
        }
    }
}

The above code fails. It shows me the contents of the index.html file. I tried different urls, but nothing worked. I need some help, please

If the file is provided by the server (and thus not "local"), then a GET request is the right way to fetch it. If your request to /static/config.json is serving you a different file, then the issue is with the server serving that path and not with the Yew component.

This is a private file that should not be known to users. That's why it should not be accessible via a public url http://host:port/static/connfig.json but should remain local to the application.
I am a beginner with Yew and I don't know if this problem has a solution or if it is badly posed.

But the question is broader: how to access server data from a Yew component. For example from a database and then present the data. This seems like a basic need and there should be a solution.

If your Yew code is to be executed on the client machine, the data must be accessible in some way to the client machine; no way around that. Perhaps you would be interested in  server side rendering instead?

Yes indeed the frontend is written with Yew components. I corrected the shot with a backend server written with actix_web which accesses the server's file system and provides the information via an api to the frontent. It works well. It was a design error on my part. Thank you for your support
